# objective-C subranging a word that starts with

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I want to substring a word that starts with '@'.
Using `rangeOfString` will only give me the start of the word and then searching again for ' '.

There must be a more elegant way, right?

Comment: `NSRegularExpression`?

Comment: NSScanner is designed to do this. It is really not to hard to use.

Comment: `NSScanner` > `NSRegularExpression` in this context.

Answer (score 0):

I'm all for `NSRegularExpression` for this situation. This is a good starting point for you.

```
NSString *string = @"Hello @world how are @you?";
// Find all words beginning with an '@' symbol.
NSRegularExpression *expression = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"@(\\w+)"
                                                                            options:0
                                                                              error:NULL];
for (NSTextCheckingResult *result in [expression matchesInString:string
                                                         options:0
                                                           range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])])
{
    NSLog(@"%@", [string substringWithRange:[result rangeAtIndex:1]]);
}
```